# Cloudera Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.14.2 and Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, spark-structured-streaming

Does anybody has been able to start structured streaming on Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.14.2 also using external libraries ( mainly the spark-sql-* ).

*Update*

Before anything else: Missing info from my previous post:  Spark is at version 2.3.0

On my remote-friend suggestion I did this:

1. I moved from python to Scala ( which is better supported and it's the native Spark language )
2. I ran Structured Streaming using other sources than Kafka.

I used a simple csv as source:

```
$ export SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10
$ spark2-shell 

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
scala> case class Amazon(EventId:String, DOCOMOEntitlementId:String, AmazonSubscriptionId:String, AmazonPlanId:String, DOCOMOUserId:String, MerchantAccountKey:String, ResellerKey:String, Status:String, CreatedDate:String, EndDate:String, ActivatedDate:String, FailedDate:String, ExpiryDate:String, LastUpdated:String, dateTimeStart:String, dateTimeEnd:String, referrerSource:String, reasonCode:String)
scala> val schema = Encoders.product[Amazon].schema
scala> val data = spark.readStream.schema(schema).csv("/user/ale/csv.csv").as[Amazon]

scala> data.isStreaming 
res0: Boolean = true

scala> val ss = data.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console")
scala> ss.start()
```

Magically this code worked.

Cloudera claims that they don't support Structured Streaming, according to this, the following code, where I just changed the source, fails:

```
val data =spark.readStream.format("kafka")...
```

Raising this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:635)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:159)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.DefaultSource
  at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:62)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
  at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
  at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:618)
  ... 50 more
```

And I'm using only the provided Cloudera libraries ( no external jars ). Please note the

```
     $ export SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10
```

that is used to force the usage of the 0.10 version ( spark-streaming-kafka-.. ) since on the cluster also the 0.8 version exists. But there is no spark-sql-kafka jar.

At this point, AFAIK, the problem is that I'm missing the correct library (jar). Spark 2.3.0 looks healthy despite all the warnings on Cloudera site.

[image]

So... is there an option to have an "unofficially official Cloudera Jar" that address this issue? Did someone find a good Jar to deploy with the code that solves this issue? The Jar from cloudera option is the better: the internal policy deny to bundle third parties jars with the code.

The other option is re-implement again all the Structured Streaming stuff using the directStreaming. This is a job I like to avoid.

Comment: If you have admin access to the cluster, nothing is stopping you from installing a recent version of Spark to run Structured Streaming (in fact, you don't even need to "install" Spark, just set it up to submit YARN jobs)

Comment: I updated the question with more useful information, spark is already at the correct version, at the end of the road the issue is about jars/cloudera policy.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is the answer to my question:

1. The library from Cloudera does exists and it is [spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.cloudera2.jar](https://repository.cloudera.com/cloudera/cloudera-repos/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.0.cloudera2/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.cloudera2.jar)
2. If Kafka is under Sentry, it will not work. Disable it.

Sadly the code need to create new group.id for each query

```
 18/11/15 10:51:25 WARN kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader: Error in attempt 1 getting Kafka offsets: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: spark-kafka-source-707ab780-c71c-408b-80dd-be1960a03dd6-360506181-driver-0
 18/11/15 10:51:27 WARN kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader: Error in attempt 2 getting Kafka offsets: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: spark-kafka-source-707ab780-c71c-408b-80dd-be1960a03dd6-360506181-driver-1
 18/11/15 10:51:28 WARN kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader: Error in attempt 3 getting Kafka offsets: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: spark-kafka-source-707ab780-c71c-408b-80dd-be1960a03dd6-360506181-driver-2
 18/11/15 10:51:29 ERROR streaming.MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 099e897f-2a44-4a50-bc57-46f898e05174, runId = b010d8d8-7b73-4f71-8ca5-f3eda47149c6] terminated
```

And Sentry will not allow these group to access the data. There is no option to avoid it since it is coded in **KafkaSourceProvider.scala** code:

[image]

Hope this can save someone else time.